# Bootstrap Template - Keep Collapsible Panel Open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toggle, sidebar

I'm using a free Bootstrap template from this site http://startbootstrap.com/sb-admin-v2

It contains a side navigation menu which also allows for collapsible second level menus, e.g., when the user clicks on the 'Charts' link, another sub menu appears showing two more links, 'Flow Charts' and 'Morris Charts'.

If the user again clicks on the 'Charts' link, the sub menu disappears. Is there anyway to make the sub menu remain open permanently? I ask this because the sub menu links in my application will be used a lot and I would prefer not to expect the user to have to keep collapsing the sub menu every time they wish to link to another page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `class='active'` for active li tags